# smtp server to use for sending email through java mail api

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am using java mail api to send email and I need to know the parameters to use for sending a test email in development environment
If I want to use `smtp.gmail.com` as the smtp mail server , it has port 465 - found on internet , do I need to set authentication to `true` with username and password also set or authentication=false in fine?
also if authentication=true is required then username, password are my gmail username & password?

Also how to set the cc and bcc addresses in the email message?

Looking for the most basic way to send email to start with
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Gmail, see the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).

Answer (score 1):

In order to use gmail as your email server, you have to set a few properties like host,port,authentication etc as per JavaMail API standards. You can get these details from 
https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Sample Code:

```
public class  SendMail
 {
    public SendMail() 
    {
     // mail properties outgoing server (gmail.com)
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    //Create session object
    Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,auth);
    //prepare mail msg
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    //set header values    
    msg.setSubject("open to it know it1");
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("yyyyyy@gmail.com"));
//Here in below line, you can specify RecipientType as TO/CC/BCC as per your requirement
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("xxxxxxx@gmail.com"));
//msg text      
    msg.setText("mail from HCL Technlogies");
    Transport.send(msg);

private class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
     public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
       return new PasswordAuthentication("nitraja2015@gmail.com","raryan500");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming question. Firstly, if you're on not an a dynamically-assigned IP address (that is likely spam-blocked by many mail servers), you don't need an SMTP server. You just take "toaddress@domain" and resolve the "domain" part to a mail exchange handler (DNS MX record lookup) make a direct SMTP connection to that server and put your mail there. You don't program this yourself because mail-handling applications or middleware should know how to do this all by itself.

If you're not on a clean static IP address, you probably can't do that because many SMTP servers will reject connections from such addresses (a common source of spam!).

In that case, your first solution is to relay through the SMTP server provided by your internet provider. (It may be secured, so you have to set up your authentication credentials.)

If that doesn't work (e.g. it is too insecure or otherwise spam-friendly and so widely black-listed) then you look elsewhere for SMTP sending solutions.

Nobody can answer this for you because the best SMTP server depends on how you are hooked up to the Internet.